# How to limit Android CPU usage?

Tags: android

I have a phone that is weak, and I want to do some calculations that takes a lot of CPU time.

How do I monitor the app's CPU usage, so I can dynamically set thread priority or executor max threads?

Answer (score 1):

Never implemented this before, but got really interested in your question and did some digging.

So from [roman10](http://www.roman10.net/2011/12/31/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/):

```
private String getInfo() {
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("abi: ").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append("n");
if (new File("/proc/cpuinfo").exists()) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/cpuinfo")));
        String aLine;
        while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(aLine + "n");
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

There's also this [post](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2009/09/read-android-cpu-info.html) that might help you out.